# How to break line content of notifications on Android

Tags: php, android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

Iam using PHP to push notification to Android and iOS device.
It perfect worked. But notifcaiton cannot be show on multi-lines.

I used '\n' character but it only working on iOS, not working on Android.

How to show notification on multi-lines on Android device ?

Answer (score 10):

Yes, the android notification don't use `\n` in default style, you should set a text in normal mode (single line) but if you want to use `\n` in your text, the `NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()` should set,

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
        new NotificationCompat.Builder(thisActivity)
                .setSmallIcon(resourceDrowable)
                .setContentTitle("My notification")
                .setContentText("Hello World")
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText("My\nMessage"));
```

Comment: Thank for responsing! I using PHP to push notification to Android device. and I don't have experence programing Android. Can I change code on backend ? or mobile app must update this code ?

Comment: Your code working with remote notification (notification pushed from server) ?

Comment: Android uses Linux standard, so the NewLine character is definitely `\n`, but the *Notifications* in android has some styles, the default style is single line, but if the app want to use multi line, the application has a chance to use a Custom Layout, if don't, the `BigTextStyle` should set to the notification style

Comment: if i want remote notification (notification pushed from server) show on multi-lines, i have to request Android developer set Custom Layout on mobile app. Thanks you :)